# scriptmanager alert not working with in modelpopup button click

Tags: asp.net, ajax, c#-4.0

in my application click on save button in modelpopup display an alert, **but it is not displaying an alert.**
my code is

```
 save button click event
    -------------------------
 protected void IbtnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {             

            showalert("Saved Successfully!!");
        }

     private void showalert(string message)
            {
                string script = @"alert('" + message + "');";
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Alert", script, true);
            }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the ScriptManager is meant to be used with async postbacks,the ClientScript class is for synchronous postbacks. So, if you are going to be postback with putton than use Client script.
ScripManger register your script block for every asynchronous postback not synchronous postbacks
Try like this...

```
  ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Alert", script, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

try the below code:

```
protected void IbtnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {             

        showalert("Saved Successfully!!");
    }

 private void showalert(string message)
        {
            //string script = @"alert('" + message + "');";
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Alert", "alert('" + message + "'", true);
        }
```

enjoy.....